# 日本語に違和感: 新規ユーザーがメタを開いた時のようこそ文

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

英語版では次のようになっています。

> This site is intended for **bugs, features, and discussion** of Stack Overflow and the software that powers it. You must have an account on Stack Overflow to participate.

修正案

> ここはスタック・オーバーフローについての**バグ報告・機能提案・討議**などを行うサイトです。参加にはスタック・オーバーフローのアカウントが必要です。

---

When a non-registered user visits the front page of meta.ja.stackoverflow.com they get this message in Japanese:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

They should get this message:

> ここはスタック・オーバーフローについての**バグ報告・機能提案・討議**などを行うサイトです。参加にはスタック・オーバーフローのアカウントが必要です。

The string is not in Transifex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ウェルカムメッセージが更新されましたのでご報告いたします。メッセージの本文は次の通りです：

> ここはスタック・オーバーフローについての**バグ報告・機能提案・討議**などを行うサイトです。参加にはスタック・オーバーフローのアカウントが必要です。