# 「ようこそ」メッセージが翻訳文字列に含まれていない

Tags: バグ, 仕様, 翻訳

新規ユーザーに表示される「ようこそ」メッセージが翻訳文字列に含まれていないようで、traducir などで作業できません。この文字列はメンテが必要と思われますので、翻訳文字列に含めるなどの対応をお願いします。

関連:

- [日本語に違和感: ログインせずにメタを開いた時のようこそ文](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1809/3054)
- [未ログイン時に表示されるボックスの文章が英語版と一致していない (削除済み)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3065/3054)
- [日本語に違和感: 新規ユーザーのサイドバーに表示されるようこそメッセージ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2423/14055)

以下、スクリーンショット。

メインサイト右サイドバー:

> [image: メインサイトの「ようこそ」]

Meta サイト右サイドバー:

> [image: Metaサイトの「ようこそ」]

Comment: 以前 aki さんとのチャットで「ようこそ！」メッセージが表示されず問題が再現できない、という会話をしたことがあったので参考までにリンクを載せておきます。https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20999?m=51594917#51594917

Comment: 再現に関して。再現が必要ならば、新規アカウントでテストするのが良いと思います。ただ、再現にこだわる必要は無いはずです。バグでは無く、単にメッセージの文面の問題ですので。

Comment: 大変時間がかかってしまいましたが「ようこそ」メッセージを改善できればと思います。コメントやご投稿本当にありがとうございます！今日の時点で、[Meta サイト右サイドバーのメッセージは改善済みです](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3785/14055)。メインサイトのメッセージ案は[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3787/14055)でコミュニティによる編集とプラス票を待ってから反映予定です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こちらは [仕様](/questions/tagged/%e4%bb%95%e6%a7%98) です。

このウェルカムメッセージは現在、サイト設定によってコントロールされています。これにより、開発者はコードを更新せずにテキストを管理し、サイトごとに異なる値を持っています。このメッセージを更新する頻度は少ないようです。今後更新する必要がある場合は、メタに新しいリクエストを投稿してください。コミュニティが変更に同意した場合、モデレーターが [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad) タグを追加することによってスタッフに連絡が可能です。